# OpenERP - field not showing in a tree view

Tags: odoo

Here is my XML file. For some reason the field "product_uom" is not showing in view's tree view. Any insights why it is happening and how I can make it show?

```
<tree string="Components" editable="bottom">
    <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
    <field name="product_id" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id, 
            product_qty)"/>
    <field name="type"/>
    <field name="product_qty"/>
    <field name="product_uom" on_change="onchange_uom(product_id, 
            product_uom)" groups="product.group_uom"/>
    <field name="product_rounding"/>
    <field name="product_efficiency"/>
    <field name="date_start"/>
    <field name="date_stop"/>
    <field name="attribute_value_ids" widget="many2many_tags" domain="
            [('product_ids.product_tmpl_id', '=', parent.product_tmpl_id)]"/>
</tree>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `product_uom` field has a `groups="product.group_uom"` attribute.

This makes it visible only to the users in that Group.
Either remove it from the tree definition, or make sure your user in in that group.

Probably what you need is just to activate the `"Allow using different units of measures"` feature on `Settings / Configuration / Sales`, `Product Features` section. Behind the scenes this activates the `group_uom` for all users.